# Can we find a quotation from an author containing the word μεγαρτός?

Tags: vocabulary, greek, reference-request

I ran into [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-the-Ancient-Greek-word-%E2%80%9CMegartos%E2%80%9D-It-exists-in-two-centuries-old-books-in-libraries-but-not-in-online-dictionaries) this morning, and had an exchange in comments with the other answerer (after answering myself). The word μεγαρτός, I'm fairly certain, means "envied", being the -τος verbal adjective of the verb μεγαίρω, "to envy". However, googling for it, I only find lexicons, not actual texts containing the word. So I was wondering: is there any author text that actually uses this word?

(Also, why does LSJ gloss it "envious"? Are they referring to the obsolete and poetic meaning of "inspiring envy" mentioned on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/envious) at "envious"?)